# Usar API do MovieDB para um aplicativo em objective-c

Tags: objective-c, api, xcode

sou iniciante em xcode/objective-c. Mas preciso fazer um projeto em que o usuário vai fazer uma pesquisa de um nome de filme qualquer e por meio do banco de dados do MovieDB, o aplicativo vai retornar o nome e o pôster do filme que a pessoa procurou.

Eu ja fiz o cadastro lá no site do MovieDB, tenho a "API key" mas não faço a mínima idéia de como começar isso no objective-c. Vocês podem me ajudar ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xj29PJgBQ24